# What is Autofac's .AddHttpClient equivalent?

Tags: c#, .net, autofac

What is the Autofac equivalent of .NET's default `.AddHttpClient<>()` method? I currently have the code defined below, which works, but it feels a bit off by doing it this way. Is there a better/shorter way to achieve this?

```
builder.Register(_ => new HttpClient())
    .Named<HttpClient>(nameof(CustomHttpClient));

builder.RegisterType<CustomHttpClient>()
    .As<ICustomHttpClient>()
    .WithParameter(
        (pi, _) => pi.ParameterType == typeof(HttpClient),
        (_, c) => c.ResolveNamed<HttpClient>(nameof(CustomHttpClient)))
    .InstancePerDependency();
```

For comparison, the default .NET method is:

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient<ICustomHttpClient, CustomHttpClient>();
```

My `CustomHttpClient`'s constructor signature is:

```
CustomHttpClient(HttpClient httpClient, ILogger<CustomHttpClient> logger, IOptions<MyOptions> options)
```

Or should I approach this differently? Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Autofac's `ContainerBuilder` has very useful `Populate` method (from [`Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection) nuget) which allows you to bring registrations from `IEnumerable<ServiceDescriptor>` (i.e. `IServiceCollection`), you can try using it:

```
var services = new ServiceCollection();
services.AddHttpClient<ICustomHttpClient, CustomHttpClient>();

var containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
containerBuilder.Populate(services);
// rest of the registrations and build
```

This way you will get the "correct" setup which will use [`IHttpClientFactory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests) with all it's benefits.

See [.NET Core](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/netcore.html) section of Autofac docs.

Also note that if you want to use it with standard setup like in ASP.NET Core you can keep the registration with build in DI for simplicity (unless you will overwrite it with Autofac registrations).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm using `builder.Host.UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory());`, which does automatic population right? So I have to define the `services.AddHttpClient<ICustomHttpClient, CustomHttpClient>();` outside of the Autofac methods? Also, how can I achieve this within an `Module`?

Comment: @Starfish yes, you should be able register this on `builder.Services`. _"Also, how can I achieve this within an Module"_ - as I shown in the answer you can create service collection in the module (per module). I would recommend to try using it in this way so you don't need to monitor/repeat the internal implementation of the `AddHttpClient` method. Also `new HttpClient()` AFAIK is still not the best way to instantiate http client.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I've modified my Module to add some dependencies like options, signalr, etc. After using `.Populate()` I register the Autofac dependencies. However I'm experiencing weird behaviour. When I register `.AddHttpClient<...>()` my Serilog logging changes its behaviour, it seems like its more verbose, looks like it's overwriting something. My Serilog registration comes right after `builder.Host.UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory());`: `builder.Host.UseSerilog((_, config) => { config.WriteTo.Console(); });`. Any idea? Other than that it seems to work.

Comment: Extra info: When registering `.AddHttpClient<...>()` in `Program.cs` instead of the Module, it works fine. For context, in my module I create a new `ServiceCollection` in `Load()`, then register the stuff like `.Configure<MyOptions>(...)`, `.AddHttpClient<...>()`, etc. Then call `builder.Populate(services)` immediately after and then use `builder.RegisterType<>` to register the other dependencies with Autofac.

Comment: @Starfish interesting. Yes, it could be overwriting something. Basically everything you call in your module will overwrite the registrations from the `builder.Services`.  Personally I would try to keep all the registrations like `AddHttpClient` within the `builde.Services` and use Autofac for registrations that do not use infrastructure  from Microsoft.

Comment: What would then be the correct approach when I need to combine different projects within my solution that need to register with `AddHttpClient`?

Comment: @Starfish It is a bit hard to tell without whole project overview.